# iOS 7 - Show Count of Searchresult in SearchBar

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm searching for a way to add a UILabel to an UISearchBar in Front of the Searchfield.

I tried to add a UILabel like that:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
  self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

  UILabel *searchResultCount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 50, 28)];
  searchResultCount.text = @"357"; //Itemscount of Searchresult

  [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar addSubview:searchResultCount];
}
```

The Result looks like that ==>
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3sel.png

How can i get this work ?
It should be

**[356] [Searchfield] [Cancel]**

Thanks for any advise

Comment: do you make use of the clear button on the search bar ? (clear button - is the X button, that clears all the text when pressed)

Comment: @Basheer_CAD: yes i need the clear button. it needs to be a additional UILabel Control in front of the Searchbar-Textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solved it. Subclass UISearchBar and make changes in layoutSubviews.

Here is my Code.

```
#import "CustomSearchBar.h"

@implementation CustomSearchBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];

  float cancelButtonWidth = 84.0;
  UITextField *searchField;
  UILabel *resultLabel;

  UIView *topView = [self.subviews lastObject];
  for (UIView *subView in topView.subviews)
  {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITextField")])
    {
      searchField = (UITextField *)subView;
    }
    else if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UILabel")])
    {
      resultLabel = (UILabel*)subView;
    }
  }

  if(!searchField) {return; }

  if (self.showsCancelButton)
  {
    if(!resultLabel)
    {
      resultLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 40, 28)];
      resultLabel.text = @"356";
      [topView addSubview:resultLabel];
    }
    [searchField setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 8, self.frame.size.width - 100 - cancelButtonWidth, 28)];

  }
  else
  {
    [searchField setFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 484, 28)];
    if(resultLabel)
    {
      [resultLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }
}
@end
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust search text position. Just add:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(65., 0.);
```

Comment: searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment looks better for me. in detail like that self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(42, 0); BUT now it cut's me the Cancel-Button Title away... see here => http://i.stack.imgur.com/hIjbq.png How can i solve that ? I simple want to minimize the Width of the Searchfield. How can i do that ?

Comment: Your search bar's width is higher than the screen's width

Comment: Thx Graver, but how can fix this Issue and set the width of the Searchbar programmatically ? Thx again